Create a custom list of servers
In Azure Monitoring logs, I have a whole bunch of data being passed from numerous servers and I want to be able to filter out certain records based on the server name being in a list of servers
Something like
AppMessages_CL
| where event contains "memory"
| extend x = parse_json(tostring(event))
| where x.daemon in table('List_of_Servers')
| extend y = parse_json(tostring(x.msg))
| where toint(substring(tostring(y.memory), 0, 3)) >= 200

The problem is that I can't find any method of storing a static list of server names that I can just refer to.
I can embed the list in the query but I'd prefer to have one single central list for all the different queries.
Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Maybe Tag the resources you want, and use https://cloudbunnies.wordpress.com/2020/09/10/azuremonitor-how-to-use-resource-tags-for-filtering-queries-in-workbooks/

You can use Azure Storgae for that. Create a CSV file and put in a blob container, you can then reference it like this using a Shared Access Signature:
let servers = externaldata(serverid:string, servername:string])  [h@"https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/data.csv?<INSERT-SASTOKEN-HERE>  with(format="csv");
AppMessages_CL
| where event contains "memory"
| extend x = parse_json(tostring(event))
| extend daemon = tostring(x.daemon)
| join kind=inner (servers) on $left.daemon = $right.servername 
| extend y = parse_json(tostring(x.msg))
| where toint(substring(tostring(y.memory), 0, 3)) >= 200



The problem is that I can't find any method of storing a static list of server names that I can just refer to.

You can do that by using below way:
Firstly, create Data Collection Endpoint in Monitor in the same region as the Log Analytics Workspace:

Then in Log Analytics Workspace, In Table section Create a table using DCR:

Then provide a name and create a new data collection rule:

Then select the  endpoint created before:

Then provide the json file, in which you want to store the server list:

My sample json file contains:
[
  {
    "ServerName": "Rith_Server1"
  },
  {
    "ServerName": "Cho_Server2"
  },
  {
    "ServerName": "Test_Server3"
  },
  {
    "ServerName": "Don_Server4"
  },
  {
    "ServerName": "T_Server5"
  }
]

then it looks like below and click on next:

Then table gets created:

Or you can also create table using code. Also check this test-fiddle with let.
